# Making images load before render()

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I use [RNFetchBlob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) to download images, videos, logos and pdf's. If a video is present, I use the video, if the video is not present but the background is, I use the background.

Whilst my application is in my **Configuring.js** this downloads asynchronously all the assets and gets my application set up.

Here's the code I use to save my assets to window/global  variables to be recalled across all screens in my app.

```
let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
RNFetchBlob.fs.ls(dirs.DocumentDir)
        .then( (files) => {
          for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            let fileName = files[i].split('.');

            if(fileName[0] === 'background') {
              window.local_background = dirs.DocumentDir + '/' + files[i];
              continue;
            }

            if(fileName[0] === 'video') {
              window.local_video = dirs.DocumentDir + '/' + files[i];
              continue;
            }

            if(fileName[0] === 'logo') {
              window.local_logo = dirs.DocumentDir + '/' + files[i];
              continue;
            }
          }

          this.props.navigation.replace('Main');
        })
```

When I navigate between screens using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) I use a generic `<Image/>` component where the source is set to `source={{uri: window.local_background}}` but my issue is when I navigate screens I will see a white flash when I navigate to a new screen that isn't yet in the stack. How can I speed this up / pre-load it so it doesn't begin loading after all the other content has already rendered?

Is there a better way to use a global background across the app?

My background **HAS** to come from the server and cannot be stored locally within the build of the application.

Comment: I have used `react-native-fast-image` to handle images that have been downloaded from a server. So far I haven't had any issues with it.

Comment: I’ll check this out and report back. I’m assuming this caches the images for future use if they show up again? Does it work well if using the same image across different screens as to not have to load the whole image again?

Comment: I used to manage my images myself (some I still do) but it became much easier using that dependency. It will download them from the server and manages all the caching for them. One thing that could be causing you an issue with flickering is the image file size, especially if the image is a large.

Comment: @Andrew so `react-native-fast-image` has pretty much solved my issue. So it initially only needs to be loaded once then it's absolutely fine no matter how many times I navigate back and forth through the components so that's great. I've just noticed that the package also has preloading of images, so I may give that a try as well. If you wanted to create an answer, I'd be more than happy to tick & upvote as it's flawless. Can't fault it. It works with large-ish images too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image caching on React Native isn't as great as it can be. After much searching I have found that using `react-native-fast-image` works great for image caching and displaying images downloaded from the web. You can find the repo [here](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image).

It is very easy to use it basically replaces the `Image` component that is provided by `react-native`.

Set up is quite straight forward (note that this package is not available on Expo)

You can install it in the following way

```
# Install
yarn add react-native-fast-image
npm install react-native-fast-image

# Automatic linking. (other linking methods listed on their website)
react-native link react-native-fast-image
```

Here is an example of using it:

```
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image'

const YourImage = () => (
    <FastImage
        style={styles.image}
        source={{
            uri: 'https://unsplash.it/400/400?image=1',
            headers: { Authorization: 'someAuthToken' },
            priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
        }}
        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
    />
)
```

I basically use this whenever any image needs to be loaded from the web.